# React functional component: how to setState multiple times in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a loop, how to update the state as many times as the loop?
For below, the updateDataset() only update the state when the loop finishes.
Is there a way to update the state along with how many times the looping occur, so that the app re-render each round of looping

```
const [dataset, updateDataset] = useState([]);
function bubbleSort() {
        //how many rounds of comparison
        var sortedArray = dataset.slice();
        for (var i = sortedArray.length; i > 0; i--) {
            //how many comparison pair

            for (var j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {

                // console.log(arr, arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
                //always compare one to the next one, that is why j+1

                if (sortedArray[j] > sortedArray[j + 1]) {

                    //swap the value
                    var temp = sortedArray[j];
                    sortedArray[j] = sortedArray[j + 1];
                    sortedArray[j + 1] = temp;
                    //update state
                    updateDataset(sortedArray.slice())
                   
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: There are no benefits of doing what you want. Even if you did, you'd get an incredibly bad performance. Instead, use a local copy of the array (non-state variable) and when the loop is done, apply the copy to the state.

Comment: `setState` can be used inside the class component not available in the functional components.  You are already updating the state in the loop, this happens in the blink of an eye and it shows you the last result. Updating the state inside the loop is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP means "set state" not "setState".

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to update the state along with how many times the looping occur, so that the app re-render each round of looping

JS only has one event loop and blocking code (like a loop) is going to be The One Thing that JS is doing. Any state changes will be queued until the event loop is free.

What you could do is replace the loop with a recursive function which calls itself with a timer:

```
const example = (data, countdown) => {
    const newData = doStuffWith(data);
    if (countdown > 0) {
        setTimeout(example, 500, newData, countdown - 1);
    }
}
```

… but be very very careful you don’t end up with two instances of `example` running overlapped (from separate calls to whatever runs it for the first time).